# How to calculate the sum of Row values in a specific column in a datagridview in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How do i calculate the sum of datagridview row content from a specific column?

Suppose, this is my datagridview;

```
Name      Score
John      35
Helen     34
James     30

Total     99
```

I want to calculate the sum of column "score" put it in the textbox.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/44ddc6cf-09e5-4f77-abb5-85650a2cad70/how-to-calculate-total-amount-in-datagridview-column-and-row-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim i,total As Integer
        total = 0
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM your_DB_table", connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                total = total + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        textbox1.text = total
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
Dim sumOfScore As Integer = 0
For Each row As DataRow in *yourDataRow*
    Dim score As Integer = CInt(row.Item("Score").ToString())
    sumOfScore += score
Next
txtYourTextBox.Text = sumOfScore.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this code which solves my problem:

```
Private Sub GetSUMofUnits()
    Dim total As Integer

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows
        total += row.Cells(4).Value
    Next
    txtUnits.Text = total
End Sub
```